# KQL/Kusto - How to generate row_number similar to SQL

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

Here is   my data set in kusto and I am trying to  generate "releaseRank" column based on the release column value.
Input Dataset:

```
let T = datatable(release:string, metric:long)  
[
"22.05", 20,
"22.04", 40,
"22.03", 50,
"22.01", 560
];
T
|take 100;
```

desired output :
[image: Expected output]

found that there is serialize and row_number kusto

```
T
|serialize 
|extend releaseRank = row_number()
|take 100;
```

But if the release value is repeated, i need the releaseRank to be same for eg. given the data set, i am not getting the desired output

```
T = datatable(release:string, metric:long)  
[
"22.05", 20,
"22.05", 21,
"22.04", 40,
"22.03", 50,
"22.01", 560
];
T
|serialize 
|extend releaseRank = row_number()
|take 100;
```

expected output
[image]

Comment: T
|serialize 
|extend releaseRank = row_number()
|take 100;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what we want.

```
let T = datatable(release:string, metric:long)  
[
"22.05", 20,
"22.05", 21,
"22.04", 40,
"22.03", 50,
"22.01", 560
];



T
| sort by release desc , metric asc
| extend Rank=row_rank(release)
```

```
    22.05   20  1
    22.05   21  1
    22.04   40  2
    22.03   50  3
    22.01   560 4
```

Comment: No reason to sort twice

Comment: thank you.  Sorting by release desc makes sense but why do we need to sort by metric  Or am i missing something here

Comment: In the expected output I saw the metric had 20 followed by 25 (for the tied release 22.05) . Thought that was what was needed , you could remove that sort clause

Comment: Corrected the double sort @DavidדודוMarkovitz , sorry for that oversight :)

Comment: ... and we also don't need `serialize` after `sort`